# How to Setup Magento2 with Multiple Domains with Multiple Databases on Same Codebase

Tags: php, magento2

**Important note: This is not about setting up magento2 on one database with multiple websites or store views.**

We've setup n domains on nginx, all points to same directory -> /var/www/html/magento2

We need magento2 to run for n different domains with n different databases on same code directory that nginx points so we will be able to release new code only one directory and all websites will be up to date. Of course each domain must be pointed to their own mysql server.

As default, magento2 stores setup based data on env.php for only 1 website setup. There are 2 possible solutions but i don't know how to implement it.

1. Converting env.php to store multiple data on array for each domains and based on request choosing the correct one from array.
2. Duplicating env.php n times to domain1.com_env.php, domain2.com_env.php and choosing the matching file based on request.

Any ideas?